# About 127.0.0.1 and IPC using sockets

Tags: windows, unix, network-programming, ipc

I think I'll use sockets on 127.0.0.1 to make simple IPC for my application. I'm targeting Windows, Mac and Linux. I have few questions:

- Can a firewall or other tool block my connection on any of those 3 OSes
- Is the connection fast? Someone told me on that on Linux, it uses pipes to transmit data.
- Can the connection be sniffed (EDIT: It can be sniffed using RawCap for example.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

127.0.0.1 ([localhost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost)) is the loopback interface. It's all internal, it doesn't hit the wire.

Can firewall block it? Not an external firewall, but perhaps a software firewall running on the same machine could.

Is it fast? [As fast as it can be](https://serverfault.com/questions/234223/how-fast-is-127-0-0-1).

Can the connection be sniffed? Not by an external device, but it could be sniffed by software running on the same machine.

Comment: It can be sniffed using RawCap for example.

Answer (score 1):

The firewall indeed can block 127.0.0.1 and some firewalls do this by default. 
At least on Windows and Linux you can use memory-mapped files (I believe you can do this on Mac as well as it's BSD-based) for data transfer and this would normally be faster than sockets due to less data buffer copying.

Comment: Memory mapped files are great, but you need an additional way of signalling when changes are made.

Comment: @MarkRansom sure, but that's not the problem either. Transport implemented this way beats localhost sockets easily (at least on Windows). We have a product, MsgConnect, which offers exactly this, so we did measurements.